# Separate file path from command in Bash under WSL2

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, prompt

Is there a way to separate the file path from the commandline in the Bash prompt in WSL2?

For example:

Current:

```
user1@DESKTOP-RMF1234:~/mywork/helloworld/tests$ ls
```

Expect:

```
user1@DESKTOP-RMF1234:~/mywork/helloworld/tests
$ls
```

Comment: This is really a feature of the shell that you are using - I'm going to assume that it is Bash and edit your post accordingly.  If it is some other shell, then feel free to correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt is set through the shell in use.  By default, this is Bash in most any WSL distribution.  The prompt that you see is also typically configured by the distribution itself.  For instance, Ubuntu provides a different default prompt than openSUSE.

Under Ubuntu, the prompt (`PS1` variable) will be set in `~/.bashrc`.  Adding a line break is fairly straightforward:

- Make a backup copy of your `~/.bashrc` in case you need to recover.
- Edit your `~/.bashrc`
- Find the line(s) with `PS1=`
- Add `\n` immediately before the `\$` near the end of the string
- Save and exit
- `source ~/.bashrc` (thanks, @phuclv, in comments), and you should see the multi-line prompt effect you are looking for.

Comment: no need to restart, just `source ~/.bashrc` again

Comment: @phuclv Good point - Thanks - Updated.

Comment: Helpful as always! Thank you!